# Laravel print HTML field attribute wrong

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to print form field attribute with PHP (Laravel)
and this is what I got:

```
@input([
            'label' => 'Labels',
            'name' => 'labels',
            'attr' => 'required',
            'value' => 'separate with comma'
        ])
```

```
@php 
// case a
$value          = isset($value) ? "value='".$value."'":"";
//case b
$value          = isset($value) ? 'value=' . $value: '';
@endphp

<input type="text" {{ $value }}>
```

And this is what I got:

```
*result a
<input type="text" value="'separate" with="" comma&#039;="">
*result b
<input type="text" value="separate" with="" comma="">
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Change the blade to use the ternary inside your element, something like this, doesn't use the `@php` and thus makes it more readable:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ isset($value) ? $value : '' }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here.

```
@php 
// case a
$value          = isset($value) ? "value='".$value."'":"";
//case b
$value          = isset($value) ? 'value=' . $value: '';
@endphp

<input type="text" value ="{{ $value }}"/>
```